# `terraform plan` fails with "Failed generating provider schemas JSON Exit code: 1"

Tags: terraform

I have a TFC Workspace which overnight has started reporting this error when a `terraform plan` is run.

```
Failed generating provider schemas JSON
Exit code: 1

Operation failed: failed generating provider schemas JSON: failed running command (exit 1)
```

Nothing has changed in the state file or the code. The error occurs when running the `terraform plan` from the my local CLI via remote exec or via the TFC GUI.

Terraform version: `v1.2.3`

Terraform providers:

```
terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vault] 3.7.0
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread] 2.25.0
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops] 0.2.1
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tfe] 0.32.1
├── module.tfc-configuration
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tfe] 0.32.1
├── module.aad-configuration
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread] 2.25.0
└── module.azdo-configuration
    └── provider[registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops] 0.2.1

Providers required by state:

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread]

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tfe]

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vault]

    provider[registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops]
```

I created a new Workspace in the TFC Organization and ran some very simple test TF code which creates an Azure RG and Public IP. It worked fine.

This feels like an issue with one of the Providers. Ive run the `terraform plan` with `TF_LOG=TRACE` and `TF_LOG_PROVIDER=TRACE`. None of the output helped me isolate the problem any further.

Im not sure what to do to resolve this.

Comment: Can you please check which version of Terraform is used?

Comment: Gah, I didnt include it. 
`v1.2.3`

Comment: Have a look at this issue at Github https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/30548 . May be it can help...

Comment: This error is being returned by Terraform Cloud rather than by Terraform CLI, and so I don't think anyone here will be able to help diagnose it. I'd suggest contacting [HashiCorp Support](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us) instead, since they should be able to work with you directly to debug this.

Comment: Thanks Martin. We opened a case with them on Friday about it. Figured I would ask here in case anyone could shed any further light.

How were you able to tell it was TFC returning the error?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so HC support have isolated the problem to the agent version used by TFC. Problem occurs when the plan is run in agent v1.2.6. Using v1.2.5 the plan completes fine.

HC support have passed the issue up to the development team who will issue a fix at a future time.

Workaround: I need to run the agent in a VM elsewhere with the v1.2.5 release. The Workspace with the problem will use the agent on that VM till HC support confirm the fix is in.